# configuration of spring servlet.xml

Tags: xml, spring, maven

i started my project maven webapplication 
and in the spring-servlet.xml i have this error i look it for but i don't understand this error i  really followed line by line i don't think that's  a space or caracter that i missed or added 
please help me

i have this err:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 57;
>   columnNumber: 9; cvc-complex-type.2.3 : L'élément 'beans' ne doit
>   comporter aucun enfant ([children]) de type caractère, car le type
>   porte le type de contenu "element-only".

this is my  Confi-Servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation=
 "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd 
">
<context:component-scan base-package="ibansys"/>
<!--   data source-->
<bean id="dataSourceRef" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="datasource" ref="datasourceRef"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.Activite </value>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.Agence </value>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.AgenceEtrangere </value>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.Banque </value>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.BanqueEtrangere </value>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.Compte </value>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.Devise </value>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.ModeDeLivraison </value>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.ModeDeReglement </value>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.ModePaiement </value>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.Pays </value>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.Piece </value>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.TPiece </value>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.Titre </value>
            <value>ibansys.model.ref.TypeDossierAva </value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hiberate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql:false}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="txManagerRef" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryRef"/>
</bean>
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManagerRef"/>
<!--dao -->
<bean id="DaoRef" class="ibansys.dao.DaoRefImpl" primary="true">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryRef" />
</bean>
<bean id="RefService" class="ibansys.services.RefServiceImpl"/>
</beans>
```

and this is my dispathsher

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    <display-name>Application</display-name>

<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>Config</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>  
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  
    </servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>Config</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Could you post the exception in English?

Comment: the Confi-Servlet.XML look ok. In which file should be the error?

Comment: in the Config-servlet.xml

Comment: Which line contains the error? On another note remove the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` property as that breaks proper transaction management for hibernate with spring.

Comment: i  remove it but  it doesn't work i forgot the bean from data source i added but the same error

Answer (score 0):

Please update the name of **Confi-Servlet.xml** to **Config-servlet.xml**

Answer (score 0):

As already answered above either change the name of your spring bean configuration file to "Config-Servlet.xml" or add these lined in web.xml file.

```
   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            Confi-Servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Note: please provide the exact location of file in  tag if file is not present in classpath.